# Not able to capture state variable value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

In my tiny web app. The top level App.js contains the structure below:

```
...
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import { ConfigureStore } from './redux/configureStore';

const store = ConfigureStore();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // make store available to all react app
      <Provider store={ store } >
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Main />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The MainComponent.js contains

```
...
import Contact from './ContactComponent';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        dishes: state.dishes,
        comments: state.comments,
        promotions: state.promotions,
        leaders: state.leaders
    }
}

class Main extends Component {
   render() {
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
                    <Route exact path='/aboutus' component={() => <About leaders={this.props.leaders} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/menu' component={() => <Menu dishes={this.props.dishes} />} />
                    <Route path='/menu/:dishId' component={DishWithId} />
                    <Route exact path='/contactus' component={Contact} />
                    <Redirect to="/home" />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Main));
```

And ContactComponent.js contains

```
class Contact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log("Current State is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
        alert("Current State is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
        //event.preventDefault();
    }

    render () {
        return (
        ...
                        <LocalForm onSubmit={ (values) => this.handleSubmit(values) } >
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Label htmlFor="firstname" md={2}>First Name</Label>
                                <Col md={10}>
                                    <Control.text model=".firstname" id="firstname" name="firstname"
                                        placeholder="First Name"
                                        className="form-control" />
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                            ...
```

The alert call in ContactComponent is supposed to display the state information after the user fills in the form and hit submit. My web app was displaying the pop up with form info before I refactored it to use redux forms. But now the display only says below. Any advice is appreciated!

```
Current State is: null
```

EDIT:

reducer.js

```
import { COMMENTS } from '../shared/comments';
import { PROMOTIONS } from '../shared/promotions';
import { LEADERS } from '../shared/leaders';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
export const initialState = {
    dishes: DISHES,
    comments: COMMENTS,
    promotions: PROMOTIONS,
    leaders: LEADERS    
};

// reducer needs the current state and the action
// in this case there is no action so just return the state
export const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    return state;
};
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Reducer, initialState } from './reducer';

export const ConfigureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(
        Reducer,
        initialState, 
    );

    return store;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty fundamental misunderstanding about redux. You should probably spend some time reading the docs or doing tutorials. Redux never auto populates component state, it is a completely separate way to maintain state.

Comment: Agree with @BrianThompson and in addition to that component's state is null by default unless you define it something else like `this.state = { name: '' }`

Comment: I have created the reducer.js and configureStore.js if that is what you are referring to @BrianThompson. I added them in the post.

Comment: `props` doesn't automatically pass down the component tree. You have passed the redux store to your `mainComponent`. But if you need to access the store state in your `ContactComponent` then you'll again have to do the `mapStateToProps` explicitly in that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the solution of this. Add the following in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        telnum: '',
        email: '',
        agree: false,
        contactType: 'Tel.',
        message: '',
        touched: {
            firstname: false,
            lastname: false,
            telnum: false,
            email: false
        }
    };
}
```